# Graph API get user id facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I do this? Im using Graph API v2.3

I am able to get the access token, but I don't know how to get the user's ID.

Comment: You'll only receive an app-scoped id....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your post is duplicated...

Btw, just send a request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...
```